# BeautifulSoup text between <a></a> not being returned

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse an ESPN webpage to get the date, time, and teams playing in each NFL game for a given week using BeautifulSoup. I am able to get most of the information, however, I am having trouble with the time information.

For some reason, the text between the a tag is not being returned.

The html for one of the a tags is:

```
<a data-dateformat="time1" name="&amp;lpos=nfl:schedule:time" href="/nfl/game?gameId=400874572">12:00 PM</a>
```

I am looking to get the "12:00 PM" in between the a tags, but instead I get:

```
<a data-dateformat="time1" href="/nfl/game?gameId=400874572" name="&amp;lpos=nfl:schedule:time"></a>
```

which doesn't have any text in between the tags.

Here is what I have used to parse the webpage.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse_nfl_schedule_espn():

    schedule = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/10").read(), "lxml")

    for date in schedule.find_all('h2'):

        #separate by game
        game_info = date.nextSibling.find_all('tr')

        date = str(date).split(">")
        date = date[1].split("<")
        date = date[0]

        #print date

        for i in range(len(game_info)):

            #separate each part of game row
            value = game_info[i].find_all('td')

            #iterate over <thead>
            if len(value) > 1:

                #away team abv
                away = str(value[0].find('abbr')).split(">")
                away = away[1].split("<")
                away = away[0]

                #home team abv
                home = str(value[1].find('abbr')).split(">")
                home = home[1].split("<")
                home = home[0]

                time = value[2].find_all('a')

                print time

                #print "%s at %s" % (away, home) 

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parse_nfl_schedule_espn()
```

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: that time is probebly generated by javascript. you can't scrape it with BS you will have to use selenium

Comment: What's the thing with converting your nodes to string and splitting on `<`? That defeats the whole point of using BeautifulSoup, which is accessing the data as a node tree.

Comment: Is the page [that one](http://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule)? There is no point concealing the url of a public page, and it makes it harder to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use something like Selenium to get the HTML. This would then allow the browser to run any Javascript. This can be done as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

def parse_nfl_schedule_espn():
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=FirefoxBinary())
    browser.get("http://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/10")
    schedule = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")

    for date in schedule.find_all('a', attrs={'data-dateformat' : "time1"}):
        print date.text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parse_nfl_schedule_espn()
```

Which would display the following:

```
6:00 PM
6:00 PM
6:00 PM
6:00 PM
6:00 PM
6:00 PM
6:00 PM
6:00 PM
9:05 PM
9:25 PM
9:25 PM
1:30 AM
1:30 AM
```

You could also investigate "headless" solutions such as PhantomJS to avoid having to see a browser window being displayed.